# Embedding multiple song players on one page without it effecting the load time

Tags: embed

I am embedding several song players (embed codes from itunes affiliate program) for viewers to preview and listen to before they buy.

The problem that I am running into is that because there are so many songs embedded, it is locking up my website.

Is there a better way to do this that will allow me to embed a lot of songs but will also allow my site to function as normal?

Comment: Loading more things will increase the load time, is this JS blocking rendering or do you have PHP code to share? ( Plugin recommendations are offtopic here, I've edited it out of your question so it doesnt get closed as out of scope )

Comment: Images can be lazy loaded - I'd check and see whether audio can too. Or, link out to the audio samples (either embed each one on its own page, and link to the individual pages; or link directly to the content on some other host) so they're not actually embedded in the page.